# new and testing .htaccess whitelisting. Is there a way to set a rule enforcement time?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

The example I am thinking of is similar to unix that has a login rule allowed times.

What I am trying to do is set up a small window if I am traveling to be able to modify the `.htaccess` file.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow

Deny from All

Allow from XX.XX.X3.*

Allow from XX.XX.X4.*
```

but have the entire `Deny,Allow` work from as an example Al0000-2355

So it allows only specific hardcoded ip ranges but for 5 minutes a day allows all so I can hop in from a non listed IP, log in and replace the `.htaccess` file with the IP range I am working at.

I guess I can set up closed and open file and have it in cron to 
`cp path/closed path/.htaccess` the ip filtered list,
and then 
`cp path/open path/.htaccess`

Not sure if there is a way to code `Deny from All if system time = 0000-2355`
in effect deny ignored from 2356-2359

ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need: Time-Dependent Rewriting

Description:
    We wish to use mod_rewrite to serve different content based on the time of day.
Solution:
    There are a lot of variables named TIME_xxx for rewrite conditions. In conjunction with the special lexicographic comparison patterns STRING and =STRING we can do time-dependent redirects:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   "%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN}" >0700
RewriteCond   "%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN}" <1900
RewriteRule   "^foo\.html$"             "foo.day.html" [L]
RewriteRule   "^foo\.html$"             "foo.night.html"
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/advanced.html